# Wikipedia crawler accents

Tags: python, wikipedia

I am trying to crawl "Muro de Berlín" from wikipedia using wikipedia python package but it doesn't understand the accent and returns a random page. I've tried :

```
import wikipedia

print (wikipedia.page("Muro de Berlín").content)

wikipedia.set_lang("es")

print (wikipedia.page(pageid="3722").content)
print (wikipedia.page(pageid="3722", auto_suggest=False).content)

print (wikipedia.page("Berlin Wall").content)
print (wikipedia.page("Berlin Wall", auto_suggest=False).content)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the encoding for your source files? Did you specify `# coding: utf-8` anywhere?

Comment: # -\*- coding: utf-8 -\*- at the start of my .py

Answer (score 0):

At the end I figure it out. It needs to be written in unicode, so the utf8 should be converted, in order to make the query.

```
variable=unicode("Muro de Berlín", 'unicode-escape')
print (wikipedia.page(variable).content)
```

Comment: Your code fooled me into thinking you used python 3, which should handle unicode by design